# How can I get a specific data from an OpenWeatherMap API?

Tags: javascript, html, openweathermap

I am currently working on a website for my school assignment (Final Thesis for VWO which is the last year of middle school in the Netherlands) where I have a sidebar which is supposed to give me the current temperature thanks to the API that I got from OpenWeatherMap.

But after searching for a few hours I still have no clue how I'm supposed to do it.

I have just "learned" HTML and CSS within the last few days, so my knowledge with them is still at the bare minimum, and as I've understood it correctly I need JavaScript for this problem which I still do not completely understand either.

I currently have this code in my `.html` which I want to show the current temperature taken from the OpenWeatherMap API instead of the 6 degrees:

---

```
<a href="#" style="float:right;">Outside Temp: 6&#8451</a>
```

---

(Reason it's a link with no destination is because that looked better in the "sidebar" with bootstrap)

But I have no idea how I can change the 6℃ to the 276.01 kelvin which is the number I got from my API JSON website:

---

```
{"coord":{"lon":5.39,"lat":51.5},"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":276.01,"pressure":1008,"humidity":69,"temp_min":275.15,"temp_max":277.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":70},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1542749460,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5208,"message":0.0034,"country":"NL","sunrise":1542697565,"sunset":1542728514},"id":2759040,"name":"Best","cod":200}
```

---

So I've been browsing and searching around the web and in w3schools and tried to get the data from the API by using the following script according to w3schools:

---

```
function loadDoc() {
  var openweathermapapi = new XMLHttpRequest();
  openweathermapapi.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var temperature = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };

  openweathermapapi.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Best&APPID=9c0299218db10c8423221d49842d8488", true);

  openweathermapapi.send();
}
```

---

After pressing a button that runs the loadDoc script I get the complete website, but I only want the "temp" part from the "main" variable and have no idea how to get it.

Comment: Just add &units=imperial to the end of your API request URL.

Comment: 1) don't have your app ID visible in your question or someone will steal it, 2) to access parts of a JSON, use dot notation (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) so it would be this.responseText.main.temp

Comment: pls let me know if it worked

Comment: I really appreciated the answer but sadly I didn't completely understand it and couldn't get it to work at the time. But my partner (our assignment was in groups) later got time and somehow got it working. So once again, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

here's an example of getting current location's weather details

first get your current system's location using this

```
var getIP = 'http://ip-api.com/json/';
```

then, it returns you your location's details in json

THIS CODE GETS ENTIRE DATA ON LOCATION and sets it to your tag

```
var weatherjson = "";
var getIP = 'http://ip-api.com/json/';
var openWeatherMap = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
$.getJSON(getIP).done(function(location) {
    $.getJSON(openWeatherMap, {
        lat: location.lat,
        lon: location.lon,
        units: 'metric',
        APPID: 'APIKEY'
    }).done(function(weather) {

      //set temperature from json to your <a> tag
        $('#mytemp').text(weather.main.temp);
    })
})
```

**Explanation of above code:-**

the sample json returned

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": -122.08,
        "lat": 37.39
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 721,
            "main": "Haze",
            "description": "haze",
            "icon": "50n"
        },
        {
            "id": 711,
            "main": "Smoke",
            "description": "smoke",
            "icon": "50n"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 11.84,
        "pressure": 1016,
        "humidity": 81,
        "temp_min": 10,
        "temp_max": 13.3
    },
    "visibility": 11265,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 1.13,
        "deg": 128.002
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 90
    },
    "dt": 1542782400,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 471,
        "message": 0.003,
        "country": "US",
        "sunrise": 1542812064,
        "sunset": 1542848035
    },
    "id": 420006353,
    "name": "Mountain View",
    "cod": 200
}
```

The main column contains the degree of your own location named (TEMP)

```
"main": {
        "temp": 11.84,
        "pressure": 1016,
        "humidity": 81,
        "temp_min": 10,
        "temp_max": 13.3
    },
```

Now we need to show the TEMPERATURE on display level

```
<a href="#" id="mytemp" style="float:right;">Outside Temp: 6&#8451</a>
```

given an identity to your temperature containing anchor tag named ID which is "mytemp"

now find the ID and update the temperature

```
//set temperature from json to your <a> tag
            $('#mytemp').text(weather.main.temp);
```